# How to replace default Magento editor by Editor based on tinyMCE 4?

Tags: magento-1.9, best-practice, wysiwyg, editor

The default Magento Editor has become less effective, no HTML5 support with weak image upload and management, so i need to upgrade editor!

I'm looking for an Editor providing strong enhancements with a sleek and totally fresh new look, yet still keep full compatibility with Magento

Please advise me

Answer (score 5):

You should try the Markdown editor module from SchumacherFM, it works great and replaces the default WYSIWYG editor of Magento.

See:
https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento-Markdown

Comment: Still waiting for the Magento v2 of this editor.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) with [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) is one option. It adds HTML5 support and a new "Drag-n-Drop" image uploader. You can download an extension to do so here:
[Amazing WYSIWYG Editor](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/redactor-jquery-wysiwyg-for-magento.html)

Alternately, you can simply add HTML5 support to TinyMCE by installing MeanBee's extension:
[Meanbee TinyMCE HTML 5 Compatibility](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/meanbee-tinymce-html-5-compatibility.html)

There are some limitations to Redactor, so we typically use the MeanBee extension.